# How can I make 2 functions run at the same time in Python?

Tags: python, function, discord.py

I'm trying to make a script where you can run a Discord bot with input instead of putting the token in the code. So far this is what I made:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='t.', help_command=None)
system_prefix = (f'\n{Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX}> {Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX}')



def token():
    token = input(system_prefix + "Enter your token: ")
    try:
        bot.run(token)
    except:
        print('Error')



def success():
    try:
        sys.stdout.write(system_prefix + 'Success!')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0.01, 0.1))
    except:
        print('Error')


token()
success()
```

But whenever I run the code, it only runs the "token" function. There are no error messages for this. I already tried threading and process but threading broke the input and process had the same result. How can I fix this?

Comment: you can run the functions in different threads. take a look at this tutorial on python threads https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/

Comment: Why do you think that *success()* doesn't run? Providing there are no exceptions, it will run "silently" unless *bot.run(token)* doesn't return

Comment: [`bot.run(token)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.run)) is blocking, meaning nothing after it will run unless the bot stops in some way. You will need to start the bot in its own thread if you want to run code after it.

Comment: You're going to need to print that out *before* starting the client, or schedule it as an asyncio task (which is probably overkill honestly)